# More questions with GUI

Tags: c#, user-interface

I am working on a assignment for school, and I am a little lost. The GUI is supposed to have a text input box where you enter a SAT score and then it converts that score into an ACT score and displays that ACT score into a textbox and then says whether or not that score is high enough in another textbox.

The SAT score is converted to an ACT score based on whether the SAT falls into these numbers. I don't understand how to write it to find out where the SAT input score falls into in terms of ACT and to display it to that textbox...

```
    SAT score > 1600    = ACT score 37 (high enough)
    SAT score from 1560-1590    = ACT score 36 (high enough)
    SAT score from 1510-1550    = ACT score 35 (high enough)
    SAT score from 1460-1500    = ACT score 34 (high enough)
    SAT score from 1410-1450    = ACT score 33 (too low)
    SAT score from 1360-1400    = ACT score 32 (too low)
    SAT score < 1350    = ACT score 31 (too low)
```

Also we had to write a try/catch to make sure that an integer was inputted and not anything else. That part I understand.

Here is my code so far without any errors.

```
    private void convertButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {



        try
        {
            double satscore;
            satscore = Convert.ToDouble(satScoreTextBox.Text);
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid input, value must be numeric");
            satScoreTextBox.Focus();
            satScoreTextBox.SelectAll();
        }



    }

    private void exitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }


}
```

}

Thank you, any help is appreciated!

Comment: So have you tried to do the conversion at all?  If so, what did you try (and what happened and why didn't it work)?  A big giant if/else if chain should be the simplest option, even if a few more flexible/elegant solutions exist.

Comment: I haven't tried any because I don't know how to even have it check which range of numbers to go to.. I'm lost. We have had no labs or homework that consisted of this so far.

Comment: @OP StackOverflow is not a homework solution board. At least try something yourself then try posting. You might be better served going to office hours with your professor or TA.

Comment: The site has a high standard of quality expected of both answers *and questions*.  You are expected to have spent time and effort attempting to solve your problem yourself before posting it here.  Consult with various resources such as your textbook, your teacher, Google, the many existing SO questions (and questions on other programming q/a sites), etc.  You shouldn't just be coming here for help as the first thing that you try.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void convertButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        String message="";
        double satscore;
        int actscore=0;
        satscore =Double.Parse(satScoreTextBox.Text);
        if(satscore>1600)
        {
            actscore=37;
            message="ACT score "+actscore+" (high enough)";
        }
        else if(satscore>=1560&&satscore<=1590)
        {
            actscore=36;
            message="ACT score "+actscore+" (high enough)";
        }
        else if(satscore>=1510&&satscore<=1550)
        {
            actscore=35;
            message="ACT score "+actscore+" (high enough)";
        }
        else if(satscore>=1460&&satscore<=1500)
        {
            actscore=34;
            message="ACT score "+actscore+" (high enough)";
        }
        else if(satscore>=1410&&satscore<=1450)
        {
            actscore=33;
            message="ACT score "+actscore+" (too low)";
        }
        else if(satscore>=1360&&satscore<=1400)
        {
            actscore=32;
            message="ACT score "+actscore+" (too low)";
        }
        else
        {
            actscore=31;
            message="ACT score "+actscore+" (too low)";
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid input, value must be numeric");
        satScoreTextBox.Focus();
        satScoreTextBox.SelectAll();
    }
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. I know what to do now. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a few if statements for this one? (Also, thought you said integer? Why are you using a double?)  I think you should do a little more research next time before asking a question such as this...

```
 private void convertButton(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     try
        {
            int satScore;
            satScore = Int32.Parse(satScoreTextBox.Text);
            checkSatScore(satScore);
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid input, value must be numeric");
            satScoreTextBox.Focus();
            satScoreTextBox.SelectAll();
        }
 }

 private void checkSatScore(int satScore)
 {
     int actScore;

     if(satScore > 1600)
         actScore = 37;
     else if (satScore > 1560)
         actScore = 36;
     else if (satScore > 1510)
         actScore = 35;
     else if (satScore > 1460)
         actScore = 34;
     else if (satScore > 1410)
         actScore = 33;
     else if (satScore > 1360)
         actScore = 32;
     else
         actScore = 31

     if(actScore > 33)
         satScoreTextBox.Text = "ACT Score " + actScore + "(high enough)";
     else
         satScoreTextBox.Text = "ACT Score " + actScore + "(too low)";

 }
```